# Creating NSFetchedResultsController sections based on type of relationship between entities

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

In an app I'm developing, I have a Core Data model which has *Users* and *Widgets* where a user can own many Widgets as their *owner* or watch Widgets as one of many *watchers*. For a screen in my app, I want to display a table view with two sections: the first lists Widgets a given User owns, while the other shows the Widgets that User is watching.

So basically what this boils down to is basing sections on whether a given Widget is related to the User by the *watchers* or *owner* relation. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two relationships between Users and Widgets. The User Entity would have ownedWidgets and watchedWidgets, whilst the Widget Entity would have owner and watchers.

```
User                  Widget
------                --------
ownedWidgets <----->> owner
watchedWidgets <<-->> watchers
```

**Edit**

Didn't notice the `NSFetchedResultsController` in the question title! The problem you've got is that the `sectionNameKeyPath` property is used by the FRC to determine sections based on one attribute. You've already done this work with the relationships, and you don't have one attribute to cover these two cases.

My suggestion would be to create two arrays from the specific User instance `ownedWidgets` and `watchedWidgets`, sorted with the same sort descriptor that you are using in your FRC, and use those for the Table View. When the FRC updates rows, you can recreate those arrays before calling [tableView endUpdates]. Saves having to alter your data model to accommodate one view controller design.

Frankly, if you already have the User object, you already have the Widgets you need via the relationships, so you don't really need to fetch anything. You might want to consider whether you really need the FRC at all.

And if you do need to use the FRC - Erik H.'s answer would be the way to go.

Comment: Yeah that's basically how I have the data model set up right now; that's not the issue. The issue is that I want to split widgets into sections based on whether they're related by the `ownedWidgets` or `watchedWidgets` properties.

Comment: Yeah the updated suggestion is how I've tackled this in the past - If you want to do a little extra work managing changes yourself it is a  good way. However if you did want to use FRC I think my answer is the way to go.

Comment: This seems like the best approach that's been suggested. I'll try implementing this approach tonight.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your data model. I think one way you could achieve this by using an intermediate object `UserWidget` and having an attribute (like `relationshipType`) for the type of relationship, owner or watcher. Then your fetch could be on `UserWidgets` and the `sectionNameKeyPath` could be `relationshipType`.

Comment: This actually seems like a pretty good solution. Perhaps a little databse-y but if the UserWidget join entity is just an added level of redundancy to the regular relationship, it just might work.